# Windows CA Server for vCenter

Tags: windows-server-2016, certificate-authority

I'm trying to implement Windows server as a CA for vCenter as instructed here : https://blogs.vmware.com/feed-items/vcenter-6-5-hybrid-certificates-with-microsoft-standalone-ca

However, I'm facing some issue, could be that I'm misunderstanding, if someone has a better understanding, kindly guide me right.

From what I read on the blog one Windows server is used for both AD and CA with vCenter server software installed on it, this is my 1st issue.

Second, I tried the above all on 1 server but cannot make it work, reasons, I cannot install vCenter on a server that is a DC (error frm vCenter), so I use 2 servers, one with AD and the second one with CA and vCenter, if I do this then I cannot apply the GPO method mentioned on the blog because GPO requires a DC, this does not work.

Then I tried a different method of having AD and CA on the same server and another server with just vCenter, in this case I cannot access the CA certificate because the CA is installed on the AD server.

Basically, everything requires everything but does not work together ?!

Anything I'm NOT understanding here.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a Windows server with AD, DNS, and ADCS in one server, with Enterprise CA configuration for GPO implementation, and VCSA configured in Workstation.